# MS in Computer Science for non-CS undergraduates

Tags: graduate-admissions, computer-science

I am a 2nd year BTech. student from Metallurgical and Material Science Engineering branch from a decent college in India.I am proficient in C++,Java ,Python programming and Web development.I really wish to pursue MS in CS from good schools in US. *How should I build up my profile for the same ?*

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot more in a US CS undergraduate program than what you are currently proficient in, I think. The course of study isn't "Computer programming in several languages", but something broader and deeper.

Find any good US undergraduate university and get a list of courses required in the major as well as the important elective courses. Find one that provides good course descriptions, not just names. That is your course of study.

You won't need all of that, but you will need quite a bit of it. Perhaps you can find local or online courses (that provide evaluation) to fill in as much of the gap as you can.

That said, most places do individual assessments of candidates at some level, but you need to get past any initial weeding-out so that you reach the second stage. And competition from "good schools" is quite intense.